# neo4j Shortest Path and Timeout configuration

Tags: neo4j

I am using Java API in an embedded graph (version 1.9.4) and using the following code to get the ShortestPath -
GraphAlgoFactory.shortestPath(expander, 15)
where expander is a expander with specific relationship types.

In rare cases, the graph (which is about 28 G on a JVM sized to 10G) just spins for more than 30 minutes. Is there a way to specify the timeout so that shortestPath query is cancelled?

Answer (score 1):

Specify the following properties to set the query execution timeout:

**conf/neo4j-server.properties**

```
org.neo4j.server.webserver.limit.executiontime=1000
```

**conf/neo4j.properties**

```
execution_guard_enabled=true
```

More information on [Mark Needham's blog](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2013/10/17/neo4j-setting-query-timeout/).